# Uncaught (in promise) undefined - Vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, async-await, vue-router

I'm facing a really strange issue where if a user with restricted permissions tries logging into my web app, they see the following error:

`Uncaught (in promise) undefined`

But this doesn't happen with users who have max permissions.

I think the issue is being caused by the re-reoute. If the user does not have page_access 1, it then routes to /holidays. The other strange thing is that this error only ever appears the once, and that's when the user first logs in. If the page is refreshed or the user navigates away to other pages, it does not appear.

**router.js**

```
Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({

  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'dashboard',
      component: Dashboard,
      beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
        if(localStorage.token) {
          if(localStorage.page_access.indexOf('1') != -1 && localStorage.page_access != null) {
            next('/holidays');
          }
          else {
            next();
          }
        } else {
          next('/login');
        }
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/holidays',
      name: 'holidays',
      component: Holidays,
      beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
        if(localStorage.token) {
          next();
        } else {
          next('/login');
        }
      }
    },
  ],
  mode: 'history'
})

router.beforeResolve((to, from, next) => {

  if(localStorage.token && from.name != 'login' && to.name != 'login') {
    store.dispatch('autoLogin')
    .then(response => {
      store.dispatch('getNavigation');
      next();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
  else if(from.name && !localStorage.token) {
    router.go('/login');
  }
  else {
    next();
  }
});

export default router;
```

***store.js***

```
async autoLogin({commit}) {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const remember_token = localStorage.getItem('remember_token');

    if(!token) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      const res = await axios({
      method: 'post',
      data: { userId: localStorage.user_id, token: localStorage.remember_token },
      url: 'https://controlapi.totalprocessing.com/api/get-user',
      config: { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }}
      })
      .then(response => {
        if(response.data.remember_token == remember_token) {
          commit('authUser', { token: token });
          return response;
        }
        else {
          localStorage.clear();
          return null;
        }
      })
      .catch(e => {
          this.errors.push(e);
          return e;
      })
      return res;
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
      return e;
    }
}
```

```
getNavigation({commit}) {
    let pageAccess = localStorage.page_access == 'null' ? null : localStorage.page_access;
    let subPageAccess = localStorage.sub_page_access == 'null' ? null : localStorage.sub_page_access;

    axios({
    method: 'post',
    data: { pageAccess: pageAccess, subPageAccess: subPageAccess },
    url: 'https://controlapi.totalprocessing.com/api/client-get-navigation',
    config: { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }}
    })
    .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
        const data = response.data;
        const tree = [];

        data.reduce(function(a, b, i, r) {

            // Add the parent nodes
            if(a.page_id != b.page_id){
                tree.push({ page_id: a.page_id,
                            page_name: a.page_name,
                            page_path: a.path,
                            page_icon: a.page_icon
                            });
            }

            // Add the last parent node
            if(i+1 == data.length) {
                tree.push({ page_id: b.page_id,
                            page_name: b.page_name,
                            page_path: b.path,
                            page_icon: b.page_icon
                            });

                // Add the child nodes to the parent nodes
                data.reduce(function(a, b) {
                    if(a.sub_page_id) {
                        const find = tree.findIndex(f => f.page_id == a.parent_id);

                        // Add the first child node to parent
                        if(!("children" in tree[find])) {
                            tree[find].children = [];

                            tree[find].children.push({ page_id: a.sub_page_id,
                                                    page_name: a.sub_page_name,
                                                    page_path: a.sub_page_path,
                                                    page_icon: a.sub_page_icon
                            });
                        }
                        // Add the remaining child nodes to parent nodes
                        else {
                            tree[find].children.push({ page_id: a.sub_page_id,
                                                    page_name: a.sub_page_name,
                                                    page_path: a.sub_page_path,
                                                    page_icon: a.sub_page_icon
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    return b;
                });
            }
            return b;
        });

        commit('authNav', {
        navigation: tree
        });
    })
    .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e)
    })
}
```

Comment: Could you include `getNavigation` action

Comment: @Dadboz - I've done that mate. I don't think it's that though as when I comment that line out, the error still persists.

Comment: I have the same issue, nothing appears to be breaking though :/

Comment: Same here... I used enso's answer, even debugged 'error' and it just shows 'undefined'. So there's an error but it's undefined? Looks like a bug to me, even with 3.1.2

Answer (score 20):

Based on my experience over the past few days, it is critical to catch errors in the function that calls `this.$router.push()`.

I find two ways are immediately quite viable:

```
handleSomething() {
    this.$router.push({}).catch((err) => {
        throw new Error(`Problem handling something: ${err}.`);
    });
},
```

and

```
async handleSomething() {
    try {
        await this.$router.push({});
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(`Problem handling something: ${err}.`);    
    }
},
```

At the moment, I prefer against the async/await technique here because of its execution-blocking nature, but the key observation you should make is that the "uncaught in promise" error itself is a known issue in JavaScript often referred to as "a promise being swallowed", and it's caused by a Promise being rejected but that "error" is swallowed because it isn't properly caught. That is to say there is no block of code that catches the error, so your app cannot do anything in response to the error.

This means it is paramount to not swallow the error, which means you need to catch it somewhere. In my two examples, you can see the error will pass through the catch blocks.

Secondary to the error swallowing, is the fact that the error is even thrown to begin with. In my application where I saw this, it was hard to debug, but I can see the nature of the error has something to do with Vue components unloading and loading as the route changes. For example, if you call `this.$router.push()` in a component and then that component gets destroyed while the route-change is in-progress, it is reasonable that you could see an error like this.

As an extension of this problem, if a route-change occurs and the resultant component tries to read data from the `.push()` event before the Promise is resolved, it could also throw this error. The `await` should stop an error like that by instructing your application to wait before reading.

So in short, investigate those two things:

1. are you somehow destroying/creating components while `this.$router.push()` is executing?
2. is the next component possibly reading data about route parameters before the route-change is completed?

If you discover some of this could be happening, consider your data flow and make sure you solve it by taming the async behaviour, not just by suppressing the error. In my opinion, the error is a symptom of something bigger.

During your debugging, add `console.log()`s into all your components' `created/mounted` and `destroyed` lifecycle methods, and also into the functions related to the route change. You should be able to get a grasp on the way data is flowing.

I suspect the nature of this issue stems from downstream usage of `this.$route.params` during an in-flight route-change. Add lots of console.logs and/or step through a debugger.

Comment: Strangely enough, without the try catch and just having the await `await this.$router.push('/account')`  the 'Promises must be handled appropriately' errors I had went away.

Comment: That would indicate that `$router.push()` returns a promise, and without await, your code moves on and downstream code tries to read the result of the promise before it is resolved. Adding `await` would delay downstream code so it reads the resolved promise rather than the in-flight promise.

Answer (score 8):

In my case I just needed to add a `catch` to the `router.push` method:

```
router.push({query: newQueryObj)}).catch(e => {})
```

See this [related issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2873) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

I also came across this issue and changing `!variable` to `variable !==` in the router did the trick.

```
else if(from.name && !localStorage.token) {
    router.go('/login');
}
```

to

```
else if(from.name && localStorage.token === '') {
    router.go('/login');
}
```

Comment: Not helped in my situation mate. It's the block above it that is actually firing, not the else if, as this happens when the user first logs in.

Comment: This helped for me, but I'm hazy on HOW/WHY this helped...

Answer (score 3):

add main.js;

```
import Router from 'vue-router'
const routerPush = Router.prototype.push
Router.prototype.push = function push(location) {
  return routerPush.call(this, location).catch(error=> error)
}
```

or;
    npm i vue-router@3.0 -S

Answer (score 2):

Our problem is the same. You can jump to this path on the login page and write:

```
this.$router.push({ path: this.redirect || '/' }, onComplete => { }, onAbort => { })
```

The wrong way to write is:

```
 this. $router. Push ({path: this. Redirect | '/'})
```

Answer (score 0):

`router.push` does return a Promise. and Promise rejection need to be handled.

instead of adding `try catch` or `.catch` everywhere in the project. you can build a global router error handler, or a component error handler by wrapping `router.push` function.

this can be implemented in your component scope or your global scope.

*be aware that the global implementation will ignore any `.catch` on the `router.push` if it is used by others. so think twice before using the global solution.

global example:

```
const originalPush = router.push
router.push = (location)=>{
 return originalPush.call(router,location).catch(e=>{
      console.log(`error in router ${e.message}`);
    })
}
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  components: {
    App
  },
  template: "<App/>",
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

if you want component scope only. then wrap `this.$router.push`. this is considered as safer solution.